# "The soil is too arid to plant seeds." Is "to plant seeds" correct here?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, subjects

I  feel something's wrong with the part "to plant seeds", whose logical subject should be a person. I wonder if the sentence is right or how to correct it the other way around.

Comment: Would you prefer, "The soil is too arid to plant seeds in."?

Comment: @Jim that's worse because then grammar fascists will come in and object to the preposition at the end.

Comment: &tox- I was not suggesting it as an improvement, just as an explanation of how the "logical subject" is not *soil*, but rather an unnamed person.

Comment: I won't object to the preposition

Comment: And really,  *soil* is not arid, *land* is arid.  Soil is dry.

Comment: So, Jim, I take it you would object to anyone referring to their birthplace as their "native soil?"  
I agree that there are times when minor distinctions in the meanings of words can be important, but insofar as Merriam-Webster defines arid as "having insufficient rainfall to support agriculture," I think the OP's sentence would be fine in the vernacular.

Comment: This sentence is correct. It means "The soil is arid so much that one cannot plant seeds now."

Comment: You're conflating the [grammatical] subject with the [etic] agent. Consider  _The soil is too arid for Jill to plant seeds._  [The soil] is the subject, [is too arid for Jill to plant seeds] the predicate ... that's how these terms are used. It depends on what grammatical part they're playing in the sentence. The 'doer' involved (or actually would-be doer in this case) is Jill: the 'agent'. // In your sentence, there is no obvious agent. The would-be/potential sower/s aren't named.

Answer (score -2):

Your sentence is fine, let's analyze it grammatically. So you have your subject:

> The soil

and your prepositional phrase:

> is too arid to plant seeds

so the prepositional phrase has a "linking verb":

> is

which links to:

> too arid

which in turn leads to a result clause.

> to plant seeds

which is fine. What's missing (but implied, so unnecessary) is the following prepositional phrase:

> in the ground.

If it sounds awkward you can add in the prepositional phrase or change the verb. For instance both are viable sentences:

> The soil is too arid to sow seeds in the ground.
>
> The soil is too arid to grow seeds.

et.c.

**Edit**: From your comments I assume you find it awkward due to the result clause needing a subject. Result clauses are a type of infinitive and infinitives do not typically take subjects. The subject is taken up by context typically and in this case the context points to a fourth person subject (which means anyone). So the sentence could expand into:

> The soil is too arid for one to plant seeds.

Which sounds more awkward, because the subject of a result clause is typically implicated rather than written when possible.

Also, as pointed out by @tautophile, the usage of the word "arid" is incorrect. Arid refers to a climate type that features a lack of humidity and typically dry soils. Thus the desert is arid, but desert sand is dry.

Comment: Except you're not planting seeds in the ground, you're planting them (or not) in the soil.

Comment: @Jim true, that one example is context dependent.

Comment: If you want to spell it out it’s “to grow seeds in ***it***”

Comment: Look at the sentence "The box is too heavy to carry". How is it that "carry" can stand alone, while "grow" has to link to "seeds (in it)"?

Comment: I think what follows "to" has something to do with the subject, specifically the subject converts to the "object" of it. For example,"the box is too heavy to carry"–carry the box;"the pen is too good to write with"-write with the pen.By the same token,"the soil is too arid to sow seeds in"-sow seeds in the soil.(" plant" replaced by " sow"). Note that the three verbs' subjects should be a person, which is hidden somehow. Can I get it this way?

Comment: The soil is dry; the climate is arid.  You can sow seeds in any type of soil, dry or wet, but they won't grow well, or at all if the soil remains too dry.  So I think what you want to say is, "The soil is too dry to plant crops in."

Comment: @tautophile yes, you are correct, I'll add that into my answer.

Comment: Soil doesn't plant seeds. :)